# Gitlab docker behind proxy - relative path problems

Tags: apache, ssl, proxy, docker-compose, gitlab

I am trying to get gitlab running with te following setup:

- in a docker (using gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest and docker-compose)
- on a relative path https://my.domain.com/git
- behind a proxy (apache) that handles SSL.

I tried many different configs, but I keep failing to get it running correctly behind the proxy. It seems that gitlab ignores the relative path. According to https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html this should work.
I also tried the old environment option GITLAB_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT: '/git', but it didn't change anything.

docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
web:
  image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
  restart: always
  hostname: 'myhostname'
  environment:
    GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
      external_url = 'https://my.domain.com/git'
      gitlab_rails['lfs_enabled'] = true
      nginx['listen_port'] = 80
      nginx['listen_https'] = false
      nginx['proxy_set_headers'] = { 'X-Forwarded-Proto' => 'https', 'X-Forwarded-Ssl' => 'on' }
      nginx['real_ip_trusted_addresses'] = [ 'proxy-ip', 'host-machine-ip' ]
  ports:
    - '80:80'
  volumes:
    - '/srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
    - '/srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
    - '/srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
```

i run an apache proxy on a seperate machine that handles SSL with lets encrypt. The apache has been running for long time already and works fine with every other application so far. Some of them also run in docker containers (owncloud, redmine, couchdb, website...).

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName my-server-name

        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains"
        </IfModule>

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ServerAdmin info@my.domain.com

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.com/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        ServerAlias my.domain.com

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        SSLProxyEngine On

        RequestHeader set X-FORWARDED-PROTOCOL https
        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Ssl on

        ProxyPass /git http://gitlab-host-ip
        ProxyPassReverse /git http://gitlab-host-ip

        ########## +redirects to other services that look the same as /git
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Ignore the apache part for now. Does the nginx direct part with non-root domain path work for you? If not then what is the error

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Could you please elaborate? I didn't really understand what you mean by "nginx direct part with non-root domain path".

Comment: What I meant is that don't have the apache https for now. And see that you are able to setup http version using just nginx and make it work with `http://yourdomain/gitlab` (non root directory). Because my setup to change `external_url` with `/gitlab` didn't work fine as such. And gitlab comments are back and forth on their website. Some related to older versions and some related to newer version of gitlab

Comment: It's definitely the relative URL. When I go to the site http://host-ip/ (without the relative 'git'), it works fine. Gitlab ignores the relative path completely.

Comment: So that confirms the issue is at Gitlab config side and not the apache

Comment: I switched to this docker image https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab and there, the relative path works just fine. I wonder why I did wrong.

Comment: It may not be you, but the official gitlab image which has an issue. Try opening a issue on their side and see whats wrong